# Get network type from iOS application

Tags: ios, afnetworking, ipv6, ipv4

Is it possible to determine network type from iOS application ? How to determine that app is using IPv6 or IPv4 network?

Answer (score 4):

There are ways in which you could test that, but it's a bad ideas in general. Trying to determine the network setup usually means that you're making assumptions, and with all the possibilities in the way networks are configured you're going to get it wrong. Networks can be IPv4-only, IPv6-only, dual stack, IPv6-only with NAT64/DNS64 etc.

The recommended way is to use hostnames with DNS and just connect to whatever you get back. That way your application will not be dependent on any specific technology and just work. If there is no network you'll notice.